# Static styles.css issues after renaming Blazor project

Tags: blazor

If I start a Blazor server from scratch. Then right-click the project and click rename.

All the namespaces change(EditedProjectName.Pages) but the using statements keep the old references(OriginalProjectName.Pages).

This is fairly easy to overcome with Find and replace
OriginalProjectName.Pages => replace with => EditedProjectName.Pages

Now the issue. Seemly randomly the site launches without proper css. The same output as I get if I comment out the static CSS in {PROJECT NAME}.styles.css which makes the sidebar etc disappear
[image: incorrect blazor index page view]

Any idea of how the project name change can cause this issue and how I can solve or troubleshoot it?

Comment: Did you a) search for the old name? It's also used in _Layout to load a css. b) do a Build|Clean and a Build|Rebuild? c) hit Ctrl+F5 in the Browser?

Comment: You can also try to use clean solution and then in the browser F12 -> application and the clear site data. Sometimes it can be a cashing issue.

Comment: I tried Rebuild but your Build|Clean advice solved it right away. A good lesson that I won't forget! Thanks a lot! @JeremiedeVos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue disappeared when I did a Build|Clean and a Build|Rebuild.

Comment: mine is still not working after following this. Checked all other suggestions, even tried using the oldproject.css but without a result. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 3):

When you rename a Blazor project, be sure to rename also the Razor CSS file bundle, referenced in

```
/Pages/_Layout.cshtml
```

as

```
<!-- Important: these are the razor css'es built at runtime -->
<link href="[Your_Project_Name].styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working while preserving the ability to rename the project by getting the name of the assembly using reflection in my _Host.cshtml file:

`<link href="@(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" />`

You would also be able to inject it as a singleton configuration in your DI container and inject it into the cshtml file.

Comment: For Blazor .Net8 I added this to the App.razor file in the Components folder.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Build Menu -> `Clean Solution`

**AND**

deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project folder finally worked.

Comment: Rebuild will do the same - a rebuild is a clean and build together